# countable and uncountable at the same time. What does that mean?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

In Cambridge online dictionary there are nouns which can be countable or uncountable at the same time.  Example https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/society?q=Societies

**1)
What does that mean?**

**2)
Also which of the following sentences is grammatical :-**

*Media has a double-edged effect on society.*

*Media has a double-edged effect on societies.*

Comment: grammarly is an internet site, it is not a word in the English language.

Comment: What is the correct word :) ?

Comment: A sentence is said to be grammatical or grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some (possibly most) mass nouns can be considered countable in certain circumstances.

Take *water* for example.

> You'll need a lot of water if you hike in the desert.

Is water a mass noun? Certainly. But now let's say you're in a restaurant with your friends and the waiter asks who wants water. You and four other friends indicate that you want water. The waiter says,

> OK, five waters, then.

*Water* has just become countable, because the word now refers to individual portions of water. It could also refer to different types of water: sparkling water, still water, spring water, salt water, and so on. Substitute another mass noun and the story is the same. Five beers, five soups, whatever.

With respect to *society* vs. *societies*, either can be used. In the singular it refers to whatever the present context addresses, most likely the society you currently live in. Or it could also refer to society in general, human or animal, throughout the ages. But if it's plural, it refers to different societies in different times or places, or both. So either usage is grammatical, but you should make sure you're using the right one for the meaning you wish to convey.

Comment: There is also: "the waters of the sea" in the Bible.

Comment: And "the waters of the heart" from "Light Breaks Where No Sun Shines" by Dylan Thomas.

Comment: Yes, I was just giving that because that literary usage is a better example than "five waters" which really means: five glasses of water and is restaurant lingo....This parallels people and peoples.

Comment: @Lambie: You don't have to be judgmental. I used that example because it was easy to demonstrate.